# How to make a String from two set of list with alternate values

Tags: java

I have two lists which contains some values,I have to make String from them so that i will take the 1st value of first list and 1 st value of 2 nd list and also 2nd value of first list and 2 nd value of 2nd list and so on..Lets says those two lists contains the interview timings.So i am giving my code here

```
List<String> interviewTimingToFrom1 = Arrays.asList(interviewTime1.split(","));
for(String a :interviewTimingToFrom1){
    System.out.println("Timing 1:"+a);
}
List<String> interviewTimingToFrom2 = Arrays.asList(interviewTime2.split(","));
for(String a :interviewTimingToFrom2){

}
```

The values contain in the 1 st and 2nd list are

```
 Timing 1:12:00am
 Timing 1:2:00am
 Timing 2:1:00am
 Timing 2:3:00am
```

So now i need to make a string like  from 12.00am to 1.00 am ,from 2.00 am to 3.00am how i can do that .Please help

Comment: Have you considered using good old `for(int i=0,...)`?

Comment: i can not make that string using alternate values how to do that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int maxSize = Math.max(interviewTimingToFrom1.size(),interviewTimingToFrom2.size());
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i<maxSize; i++)
{
    if (i < interviewTimingToFrom1.size())
        result.append(interviewTimingToFrom1.get(i));

    if (i < interviewTimingToFrom2.size())
        result.append(interviewTimingToFrom2.get(i));
}
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot the actual method call on that line. You're getting the max size between the two lists. Check my edited answer.

Comment: @Nik Don't you think it should be `min`?

Comment: yah it worked but i wanted to make it a String like from 12.00am to 1.00 am ,from 2.00 am to 3.00 am ,can you help

Comment: @lucifer Concatenate them. In other words use `+` operator like `System.out.println("foo"+value+"bar"+otherValue);`.

Comment: @lucifer If you want to create string, you can use `StringBuilder` and its `append` method.

Comment: Can anyone plesae help me to make that string

Comment: @Pshemo Why would you want `min`? You want to get the maximum number of iterations needed to loops fully through both lists. If you use `min`, you'll have some elements left over in whichever list is larger. That's why I do a check to make sure `i` is a valid index of each list. Of course, if the lists are both the same size, it doesn't really matter either way.

Comment: @lucifer I edited my answer again. It now saves the results in a `StringBuilder` and outputs the results once the loop is done.

Comment: @Nik your answer working perfectly for me thanks man,but can you do a little bit addition i need FROM 12.00 am to 1.00am  and FROM 2.00PM TO 3.00 ????

Comment: @Nik Usage of `min` or `max` depends on what OP wants. If we have lists like `[a,b,c]` and `[1,2]` OP may want to generate only `a1,b2` but with your solution it will generate `a1,b2,c`. Generally first variant with only `a1,b2` is more common, but as I said, it all depends on what OP wants.

Comment: @lucifer All of the pieces that you need to figure this out are in the answer. It's a pretty simple fix - either add another `append()` call, or do a String concatenation (`interviewTimingToFrom1.get(i) + "some string"`). I'm sure you can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
   List<String> interviewTimingToFrom1 = Arrays.asList(interviewTime1.split(","));
   List<String> interviewTimingToFrom2 = Arrays.asList(interviewTime2.split(","));

    if (interviewTimingToFrom1.size() == interviewTimingToFrom2.size()) {
        int noOfSlots = interviewTimingToFrom1.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfSlots; i++) {
            System.out.println("from " + interviewTimingToFrom1.get(i)
                    + " to " + interviewTimingToFrom1.get(i));
        }

    } else {
        System.out.println("No match");
        int noOfSlots = (interviewTimingToFrom1.size() > interviewTimingToFrom2
                .size() ? interviewTimingToFrom2.size()
                : interviewTimingToFrom1.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfSlots; i++) {
            System.out.println("from " + interviewTimingToFrom1.get(i)
                    + " to " + interviewTimingToFrom2.get(i));
        }
    }
```